# Load content in a user control (Webpart in Kentico) while scrolling down, using web service in ASP.Net and AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, kentico

I have a webpart (user control) in Kentico in which I need to load content while scrolling down the page to preview the content of a tree node.
For this, I have already written AJAX code and tried writing the WebMethod in the code behind itself of same user control and call it using the parent ASPX page url but the url is dynamic and changes with the node name which is selected in the tree. I tried with `window.location.href` also but no success.

Then I created a web service and wrote that WebMethod inside the service which gets hit on the scroll and I get content also but now I wasn't able to append the content to the existing content. Actually I want to use the existing code somehow with some page index or something (for now I used specific numbers in the code) to load may be 3 rows at the page load and 3 rows always while scrolling down. The code snippet is provided below:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtSortedDocRows.AsEnumerable()){

                    int rowNumber = int.Parse(row["RowNumber"].ToString());

                    if (rowNumber >= 0 && rowNumber <= 2)
                    {
                        TreeNode document = TreeNode.New(row);

                        EditableDocumentPreview edp = (EditableDocumentPreview)Page.LoadControl("~/EditableDocumentPreview.ascx");
                        edp.Document = document;
                        // plcContainer manages child controls' viewstate by ID, so set them to be node-specific.
                        // (Not document-specific -- due to linked documents, one document might be associated with multiple edps.)
                        edp.ID = "edp_" + document.NodeID;
                        plcContainer.Controls.Add(edp);

                        ChildCount++;
                    }
}
```

Please let me know if any other information is required and thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Why are you unable to "append the content"? Are you getting any errors along the way?

Comment: Actually, one user control (**EditableDocumentPreview** in the above code snippet) is being called inside the other user control (this one is used as a webpart) and so as I'm getting the required content from the web service, I want that to append as like the above code which is done using a loop.
Else please suggest me any other way to do this like binding the **EditableDocumentPreview** user control on success of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [webpart on the Kentico DevNet Marketplace](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/web-parts/seo-friendly-infinite-scroll-lazy-load-repeater) which already does this it's called the "Infinite Scroll / Lazy Load Repeater".  If it's not exactly what you need, take inspiration from the code in it to make your own.  I'm not saying this will fix your problem but it will allow you to get a lot closer without having to write any code.